# PHP Unit and JWT

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, phpunit

I don't understand my unit test when I try to log in.

Here is my code:

```
class UserTest extends ApiTestCase
{ 
  public static function userLoggedIn(): string
    {
        $response = static::createClient()->request('POST', 'http://localhost:3000/api/login',
        [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ],
            'json' => [
            'username' => 'foobar@example.com',
            'password' => 'monPassword',
        ]]);
 
        return $response->toArray()['token'];
    }
}
```

And this is my error on terminal :

```
1) App\Tests\Func\UserTest::testGetUsers
Symfony\Component\HttpClient\Exception\ClientException: HTTP 401 returned for "http://localhost:3000/api/login".
 
C:\wamp64\www\otime-api\vendor\api-platform\core\src\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Response.php:80
C:\wamp64\www\otime-api\vendor\api-platform\core\src\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Response.php:94
C:\wamp64\www\otime-api\vendor\api-platform\core\src\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Response.php:125
C:\wamp64\www\otime-api\tests\User\UserTest.php:24
C:\wamp64\www\otime-api\tests\User\UserTest.php:36
```

Knowing that if I do the test on Postman with the same data, I receive my JWT token without problem.

Where can my mistake come from?  Is there anything to configure with PHP Unit?

Thanks in advance

Julien

Hi,
This is my Security.yaml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        # dev:
        #     pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        #     security: false           
        #     pattern: ^/api/login
        #     lazy: true
        #     provider: app_user_provider
        #     custom_authenticator: App\Security\APICustomAuthenticator

        #     # activate different ways to authenticate
        #     # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#the-firewall

        #     # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
        #     # switch_user: true


        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure


        api:
            pattern:   ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~


        # Login pour admin
        main:
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login
                enable_csrf: true

            logout:
                path: app_logout
                target: app_login   

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_SUPER_USER: [ROLE_USER]
        ROLE_ADMIN : [ROLE_SUPER_USER]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN]
        ROLE_APP_MANAGER: [ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN]

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        - { path: ^/api, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
        # - { path: ^/api,       roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            # By default, password hashers are resource intensive and take time. This is
            # important to generate secure password hashes. In tests however, secure hashes
            # are not important, waste resources and increase test times. The following
            # reduces the work factor to the lowest possible values.
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 # Lowest possible value for bcrypt
                time_cost: 3 # Lowest possible value for argon
                memory_cost: 10 # Lowest possible value for argon
```

And my postmann :
[image]

Comment: It looks like `/api/login` is not accessible for unauthenticated users. How is configure your security.yaml file ?

Comment: Hi Spomky, thank's for your answer. Updated with my Security.yaml

Comment: "if I do the test on Postman with the same data" <--- can you show that too?

Comment: Hey Zerkms, thank you, i have editing with Postman screen shot. thank you

Comment: Few additional comments: you can pass `'/api/login'` instead of `'http://localhost:3000/api/login'` in your test. The `headers` key is not needed (will be added by the client automatically as you pass a json). What is the `Cookie` header in Postman? As you are stateless, there is no reason for such header parameter. Can you make sure the database used in tests contains the user `foobar@example.com`?

Comment: Thnak's Spomky, it's right now. I thought that phpunit was doing the tests in the "myDataBase" database but it does it in "myDataBase_test", I inserted my user into this database and it works now